"ReferenceError: self is not defined" in build using powerbi-client-react with nextjs
I'm using a NextJs 14.2.6 application with Typescript and it's showing this error in powerbi-client-react 1.4.0 (I'm using powerbi-client 2.23.1 too): "ReferenceError: self is not defined"
The error complete:
 Generating static pages (17/27)  [=== ]ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at ./node_modules/window-post-message-proxy/dist/windowPostMessageProxy.js (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:55:173)
    at m (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:55:5101)
    at ./src/factories.ts (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:35:146)
    at m (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:55:5101)
    at C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:57:482
    at e (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:57:2593)
    at 30399 (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:57:2606)
    at t (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 49314 (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:57:3005)
    at Object.t [as require] (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143) {
  digest: '1669349193'
}

Error occurred prerendering page "/auth/dashboard". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at ./node_modules/window-post-message-proxy/dist/windowPostMessageProxy.js (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:55:173)
    at m (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:55:5101)
    at ./src/factories.ts (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:35:146)
    at m (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:55:5101)
    at C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:57:482
    at e (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:57:2593)
    at 30399 (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:57:2606)
    at t (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)
    at 49314 (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\app\(main)\auth\dashboard\page.js:57:3005)
    at Object.t [as require] (C:\Users\Vitor\Desktop\Ampliar-Mente-Web\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:143)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /(main)/auth/dashboard/page: /auth/dashboard

I've tried searching on forums and I couldn't find anything. Does anyone have any idea what might work? Thanks in advance.
Here's the code I'm using:
'use client';
import React from 'react';
import { models } from "powerbi-client";
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

let PowerBIEmbed: any;
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  PowerBIEmbed = dynamic<any>(() => import('powerbi-client-react').then(mod => mod.PowerBIEmbed), { ssr: false });
}

export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <>
      {typeof window !== 'undefined' && <PowerBIEmbed
        embedConfig={{
          // Config here
        }}
      />}
    </>
  );
}


There's no need to use powerbi-client-react package.
Error is showing because the module is desgined for browser environment is executed in a Node.js or server-side environment. The powerbi-client library is designed to run in a browser and interacts with the DOM, so this error can occur if it is being imported or executed on the server side.
Here' the way you can dynamically import the package in nextjs code.
"use client";

import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const ReportPage = dynamic(
  () => import("../../src/components/ReportPageComponent"),
  { ssr: false },
);

export default ReportPage;

ReportPageComponent.tsx
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { powerbiService } from "src/services";

const ReportPageComponent = () => {
  const [embedToken, setEmbedToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [embedUrl, setEmbedUrl] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchEmbedToken = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await powerbiService.get();
        setEmbedToken(response.embedToken);
        setEmbedUrl(response.embedUrl);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching embed token:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchEmbedToken();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (embedToken && embedUrl) {
      (async () => {
        const powerbiClient = await import("powerbi-client");
        const embedConfig: powerbiClient.models.IReportEmbedConfiguration = {
          type: "report",
          tokenType: powerbiClient.models.TokenType.Embed,
          accessToken: embedToken,
          embedUrl: embedUrl,
          id: process.env.BI_REPORT_ID,
          settings: {
            filterPaneEnabled: false,
            navContentPaneEnabled: false,
          },
        };

        const embedContainer = document.getElementById("embedContainer");
        if (embedContainer) {
          const powerbi = new powerbiClient.service.Service(
            powerbiClient.factories.hpmFactory,
            powerbiClient.factories.wpmpFactory,
            powerbiClient.factories.routerFactory,
          );
          powerbi.reset(embedContainer);
          powerbi.embed(embedContainer, embedConfig);
        }
      })();
    }
  }, [embedToken, embedUrl]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="embedContainer" style={{ height: "49rem", width: "100%" }}></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReportPageComponent;

